# Can we implement any other date format instead of English date format i.e January ,February in FullCalender?

Tags: reactjs

I need to use Devanagari calender in the full calender instead of English calender in FullCalender.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/locale), you can. You can even try and set the locale to 'hi' in the [live demo](https://fullcalendar.io/demos).

To set the locale to Hindi in your project (to my knowledge, Hindi uses Devanagari writting):

```
import { Calendar } from '@fullcalendar/core';
import hiLocale from '@fullcalendar/core/locales/hi';
...
let calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
  locale: hiLocale
});
```